# Cómo conservar el canal alfa del png al crear webp con php

Tags: php

Necesito que al subir un png con transparencia, pueda obtener un webp generado por php que siga conservando esa transparencia, el problema es que estuve buscando cómo solucionarlo y no encontré ninguna que funcionara :S

El código funciona bastante bien así como está para imágenes tipo jpg que no manejan transparencias

```
$max_ancho="1280"; $max_alto="1280"; $calidad=7;
$medidasimagen=getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);

$nombrearchivo=$file['name']; $rtOriginal=$file['tmp_name'];

if($file['type']=='image/jpeg'){ $original = imagecreatefromjpeg($rtOriginal); }
elseif($file['type']=='image/png'){ $original = imagecreatefrompng($rtOriginal); }
elseif($file['type']=='image/gif'){ $original = imagecreatefromgif($rtOriginal); }
elseif($file['type']=='image/webp'){ $original = imagecreatefromwebp($rtOriginal); }
elseif($file['type']=='image/bmp'){ $original = imagecreatefrombmp($rtOriginal); }

list($ancho,$alto)=getimagesize($rtOriginal);
$x_ratio = $max_ancho / $ancho; $y_ratio = $max_alto / $alto;

if( ($ancho <= $max_ancho) && ($alto <= $max_alto) ){
    $ancho_final = $ancho;
    $alto_final = $alto;
} elseif (($x_ratio * $alto) < $max_alto){
    $alto_final = ceil($x_ratio * $alto);
    $ancho_final = $max_ancho;
} else{
    $ancho_final = ceil($y_ratio * $ancho);
    $alto_final = $max_alto;
}

#AQUÍ ES DÓNDE ESTÁ LA MAÑA PARA LA TRANSPARENCIA... SEGÚN LO QUE HE BUSCADO
$lienzo=imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_final,$alto_final);
imagecopyresampled($lienzo,$original,0,0,0,0,$ancho_final, $alto_final,$ancho,$alto); imagedestroy($original);

$newTemp=tmpfile(); $tmpPath=stream_get_meta_data($newTemp)['uri'];
imagewebp($lienzo, $tmpPath, 77); $file['tmp_name']=$tmpPath;
$extension="webp";
```

Así mismo como está, al subir un png con transparencia, el fondo o la zona transparente queda en negro... (como dato, probé con 2 png diferentes, y en ambos tuve el mismo resultado)

Probé poner esto justo después de donde defino $lienzo pero quedó igual...

```
imagepalettetotruecolor($lienzo);
imagealphablending($lienzo, true);
imagesavealpha($lienzo, true);
```

¿Alguna idea?. Será que el problema es con la función imagecopyresampled ?

Actualización: Lo estoy haciendo en PHP 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Probado con 7.3.0 -- funciona.

Probado con 5.6.15 -- no funciona.

NOTA: Es posible que sólo funcione con versiones más nuevas de PHP

Código:

```
// Imagen png a procesar

$pngimg = imagecreatefrompng($file);

// Obtener dimensiones de la imagen

$w = imagesx($pngimg);
$h = imagesy($pngimg);;

// Crear canvas

$im = imagecreatetruecolor ($w, $h);
imageAlphaBlending($im, false);
imageSaveAlpha($im, true);

// Por defecto el canvas es negro, debes hacerlo transparente

$trans = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $w - 1, $h - 1, $trans);

// Copiar el png al canvas

imagecopy($im, $pngimg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);

// Por último, guardar el canvas como webp

imagewebp($im, str_replace('png', 'webp', $file));

// Listo!

imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Excelente, funciona muy bien!.
Probado en PHP 8

Muchas gracias :)